# Weak warning for a parameter not used but needed with Fast API

Tags: python, pycharm, fastapi

I use a custom exception handler with Fast API:

```py
class CustomException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, err_message: str):
        self.err_message = err_message

@app.exception_handler(CustomException)
async def custom_exception_handler(request: Request, exc: CustomException):
    return JSONResponse(content={"error": exc.err_message})
```

Pycharm put the 'request: Request' as a weak warning:

> ''Parameter 'request' value is not used'' since it's not used in the code.

However, if I remove the parameter, I get a Fast API error when running the code.
So I wonder if this is a PyCharm 'bug', if we can call it that way ?

Comment: Just disable the warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR:
You use the `_` as a replacement of the name or a prefix

Answer:

For that you don't disable the warning as suggest in the comments, it's is considered a bad practice to disable warnings because they exist for a reason. A better approach is to do some root cause analysis understand the warning by googling why and find a proper code change that removes it.

Working with linters in general some times it will be possible to think that there is no way to fix a warning or a suggestion other than causing another one to pop up. But you are getting there: you have to pick a solution that enhances code readability and maintainability without breaking any more rules or the actual software

In general in python there are some methods that will require parameters even if you don't use it because the above infrastructure using them is expecting to recieve a method with a certain signature template. For example when defining serverless lambda functions  it is expected to have a `event`and a `context` but you might as well not have any relevant information in the incoming event or the execution context to use.

> You have to learn how to discard parameters while keeping them. For that you use the `_` as a replacement of the name or a prefix

```
def lambda_example(event, context):
    """This raises a warning ⚠️"""
    print(event)


def second_example(event,_):
    """This does not ✔️"""
    print(event)


def third_example(_event,_context):
    """This does not either ✔️"""
    print("this does not care about it's parameters")
```

Comment: Very clear explanation! Fixed the issue for me :)

Comment: Except this `_` theory doesn't work when you actually NEED to put `request: Request` in the function arguments. Case and point? When using a rate-limit decorator such as with slowapi. It's the decorator eating up the `Request`. Enter in the point of having single line exemptions to ignore warnings. For example: `def func(request: Request):  # pylint: disable=unused-argument`. It if was "bad practice" to ignore single lines (or entire blocks of code), then that functionality would be completely removed from any and all linters.

Comment: @BrandonStivers it is  not  a bat practice per se but is an inconsistency on your linting configuration ; you are basically saying  I agree with this rule but i don't enforce it in my code. This warning is designed to help improve code quality by identifying and flagging code that includes parameters that are defined but not used within the function body. to prevent code bloat and to encourage developers to write cleaner, more efficient code. Unused arguments can indicate code smells and design issues, such as unused imports, copy-pasting from other functions, or bad function signatures.

Comment: @lcarvajal except you ignore the false positives given by linters, code in which you do not control. Again, go ahead try using your theory while using FastAPI and SlowAPI as a rate limeter. You're using valid function arguments that are used in the function itself, but MyPy gives a false positive.  You run over to the SlowAPI code owners and tell them they don't know what they are doing. What projects you maintain again?

Comment: it is not a false positive , you have not prefixed the argument with a `_`   and is not used internally  in the method  that exposes it therefore you have  a linter  you don't need to name  it request ,  you need to type hint it  as Request type `def func(_request: Request)...` please understand  that linters are not intelligent they are barely pointing the obvious. it is you as the developer who has to figure  ot the solution that shuts down all linter warnings